# How to set the background color for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, background-color

I want to change the background color of the webview. Not for the HTML document it display but for the actual scroll view which can be scrolled. If you scroll a web view you see a gray background color. I have tried below code for this but not working for me. Actually I want to make it transparent.

```
    [detailWebV setOpaque:NO];
    detailWebV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following has worked for me . This is what I wanted , when I scroll down the web view , the background should be transparent .

```
     [webV setOpaque:YES];
     webV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Thank you all !!!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
myWebView.opaque = NO;
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:
@"<html><body style='background-color: transparent'>
       Content Here</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: this is an answer i've been looking for .. for 3 days

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to set it by using JavaScript:

```
[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.background = '#000000';"];
```